# Input string in C++ do while

Tags: c++, string, input

I'm trying to read a string as an input.

The string can only contain A C G and T letters and the length can't be more than 20000.

If the length is more than 20000 or it contains any other letter than A C G or T print out "error" and read again.

EXAMPLE INPUT: ACCGGTATTTACG

Here's my code and currently it prints error for every input.

```
int main()
{
string str;
string tmp;
bool hiba;
do{
    cout<<"Str: ";cin>>str;
    for(int x = 0;x < str.length();x++){
        hiba = (cin.fail() || str[x] != 'A' || str[x] != 'C' ||str[x] != 'G' ||str[x] != 'T' || str.length() > 20000);
        if(hiba){
            cout<<"Error\n";
            cin.clear();
            getline(cin,tmp);
            break;
        }
    }

}while(hiba);
}
```

Comment: Time to learn about `switch` statements.

Comment: What is `dns`? That's not shown. Try splitting out the validation into a function you can call. You also use a mixture of `getline` and `cin >> str` for no apparent reason. These work quite differently. One will contain linefeeds.

Comment: It's str.length() i forgot to change it before posting.

Comment: This code makes almost no sense to me, as you read in a string, then verify letters, then take in more input, once line character? You're going to have to give us an example of the input you're using and the expected process you're performing. If this is just "Validate string contains only characters ACGT" then this is not quite it, but it could be fixed if that's the case.

Comment: Is that inner `if (hiba)` supposed to be like a "error, re-read line" kind of trap? If so you need to bust out of that `for` loop first.

Comment: Is there any character that isn't unequal to at least one of `'A'`, `'C'`, `'G'`, or `'T'`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct transliteration of your requirements. Note the use of `std::string::find_first_not_of` to find "bad" characters. Also note that it returns an empty string should `std::cin >> sequence` fail. You need to handle that corner case.

```
std::string read_dna(int max_length) {
  std::string sequence;
  while (std::cin >> sequence) {
    if (sequence.length() > max_length ||
        sequence.find_first_not_of("ACGT") != std::string::npos) {
      std::cerr << "error" << std::endl;
    } else { 
      return sequence;
    }
  }
  return std::string{};
}
```